# FM Radio: can we implement FM Radio and create and application of it?

Tags: java, android

I wonder if i can create an FM Radio app. Any directions will be appreciated.. I found some interesting thing on github [here](http://gitorious.org/0xdroid/packages_apps_fm/trees/56e3111004ba2db25b8a2f77b0474bb48b93fd8b).. but

- unable to find the respective jar for the same..
- unable to find "android.hardware.fmradio" package and related thing

Can we implement the same? please help

Comment: Please narrow your question. This question is to bread for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @UwePlonus any pointers will be appreciated. I need to know the different APIs for this.. And if this can be done..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library below to develop a FM Radio App for android. But this library is firmware dependent. [See here](http://mmbtools.crc.ca/content/view/53/33/)

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Soni has created a **Module** for **[FM radio for the 2011 Xperia™ phones](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/code-example-module/fm-radio-for-the-2011-xperia-phones/)**. It is open source and can be used by custom ROM developers. Have a look, may this help you.

Read [this](http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/07/13/nexus-one-finally-receives-fm-radio-support-not-thanks-to-google-but-the-android-community-coming-to-a-rom-near-you/) blog for another resource.

Comment: actually I was looking for something which will run on all the devices, Gingerbread and above.. thanks for the help anyways

Comment: Actually it is not possible. FM is provided by manufacturer and OS is modified at ROM level. So some what difficult to achieve but not impossible.

Comment: I understand.. thanks for your directives Chintan